# Can I avoid adapter classes when composing heterogeneous collections?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, collections, adapter

I need a single collection of "processor" classes (I happen to be using Java) that can operate on a concrete shape, say a circle.  Some of the classes can operate on the abstract shape, while others require the concrete circle class.

The problem is that, I don't know of any language or design mechanism I can use to avoid adapter classes like `CircleSaver`.  If I can't avoid this, I'll be creating an adapter method for each processor class that requires a concrete shape.

Is there a name for this problem / pattern?  Is there a solution to it?

```
List<CircleProcessor> circleProcessors = new ArrayList<CircleProcessor>
 (Arrays.asList(new CircleDrawer(), new CircleSaver()));

interface ShapeProcessor {
    void execute(Shape circle);
}

interface CircleProcessor {
    void execute(Circle circle);
}

class CircleDrawer implements CircleProcessor {
    public void execute(Circle circle) {
        // Draw circle
    }
}

class ShapeSaver implements ShapeProcessor {
    public void execute(Shape shape) {
        shape.save();
    }
}

// Adapter method that I would love to avoid
class CircleSaver implements CircleProcessor {
    public void execute(Circle circle) {
        new ShapeSaver().execute(circle);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After asking the question, I think I've come up with a much better version that uses generics.  If there's a better solution and/or a name for this problem, please let me know!

```
    List<ShapeProcessor<Circle>> circleProcessors = new ArrayList<ShapeProcessor<Circle>>(
 Arrays.asList(new CircleDrawer(), new ShapeSaver<Circle>()));

public interface ShapeProcessor<T extends Shape> {
    void execute(T t);
}

public class CircleDrawer implements ShapeProcessor<Circle> {
    @Override
    public void execute(Circle circle) {
        // Draw circle
    }
}

public class ShapeSaver<T extends Shape> implements ShapeProcessor<T> {
    @Override
    public void execute(T t) {
        t.save();
    }
}
```

Comment: Generics are probably indeed the way to go.

Answer (score -1):

It looks a lot like the [Strategy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) pattern. I'd make `CircleProcessor` an abstract class with a [template method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern):

```
abstract class CircleProcessor implements ShapeProcessor {
  public final void execute(Shape shape) {
    if (!(shape instanceof Circle)) return; // ignore everything but circles

    execute((Circle) shape);
  }

  protected abstract execute(Circle circle);
}
```

Assuming `Circle` extends `Shape` here, but it lets you add all kinds of processors to your collection and all that support your object will do their work.

Comment: I very much appreciate you taking the time to try to answer.  The issues with the answer are: The proposed solution is not type safe.  For example, it would incorrectly allow CircleProcessors to exist within collections of SquareProcessors.  It also forces me to use up my only inheritance shot.  The problem/pattern I am looking to name is to avoid adapter classes like CircleSaver.

Comment: Actually, your type safety is only there at compile time. If you forget to use generic bounds somewhere, you'll still end up with the problems you mention. In addition, the code I wrote is basically what the compiler also generates for your generic code. I agree that if you never want to process generic containers of shapes, your solution is better, but mine is what you would have had to do before generics existed in the language.